# MDX filtration by more granular value

Tags: date, filter, mdx

I have a MDX query:

```
    SELECT
    ({[Measures].[Sales Count]}) ON COLUMNS, 
    {Filter([Creation Date].[Day].Members, 
    ([Creation Date].[Day].CurrentMember.Name >= '2016/09/01' AND 
    [Creation Date].[Day].CurrentMember.Name <= '2016/09/05'))} ON ROWS  
           FROM [Date Sales Schema]
```

It allows me to select sales count for date range. 
Also I might filtering by minutes by replace [Creation Date].[Day] in query to [Creation Date].[Minute]. 
BUT if I want **filtering by minutes**, and get **result** with sales count by **days**, I dont know, what query must I write?

For example:
*Filtering from September 8 - 15:57 until September 10 - 13:35 - the result should be:*

- the number of sales of the 8th September 15:57 - 23: 59
- the number of sales of the 9th September at 24 hours
- the number of sales of the 10th September 00:00 - 13:35

Such query is near the decision:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Sales Count]} ON COLUMNS
 ,Exists
  (
    [Creation Date].[Day].MEMBERS
   ,Filter
    (
      [Creation Date].[Minute].MEMBERS
     ,
        [Creation Date].[Minute].CurrentMember.Name >= '2016/09/01 15:57'
      AND 
        [Creation Date].[Minute].CurrentMember.Name <= '2016/09/10 15:57'
    )
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Date Sales Schema];
```

BUT, for example, if I if a sale was made in 10.02.2016 23:55 , and the filter begins on 10.02.2016 23:54 , the result of a request to show me all the sales for 10.02.

Next query is calculate the sum of all period and print the sum as measure for every day-dimension:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Day Period Sales Count] AS Aggregate(Filter
    (
      [Creation Date].[Minute].MEMBERS
     ,
        [Creation Date].[Minute].CurrentMember.Name >= '2016/09/01 07:27'
      AND 
        [Creation Date].[Minute].CurrentMember.Name <= '2016/09/01 15:57'
    )
)
SELECT 
([Measures].[Day Period Sales Count]) ON COLUMNS ,{[Creation Date].[Day].[2016/09/01],[Creation Date].[Day].[2016/09/02]} ON ROWS
FROM [Date Sales Schema]
```

But it do not divide results by days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the minute filter in a sub-select:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Sales Count]} ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    Filter
    (
      [Creation Date].[Day].MEMBERS
     ,
        [Creation Date].[Day].CurrentMember.Name >= '2016/09/01'
      AND 
        [Creation Date].[Day].CurrentMember.Name <= '2016/09/05'
    )
  } ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    [Creation Date].[Minute].&[1] : [Creation Date].[Minute].&[10] ON 0
  FROM [Date Sales Schema]
);
```

Without a `subselect`:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Sales Count]} ON COLUMNS
 ,Exists
  (
    [Creation Date].[Day].MEMBERS
   ,Filter
    (
      [Creation Date].[Minute].MEMBERS
     ,
        [Creation Date].[Minute].CurrentMember.Name >= '2016/09/01 15:57'
      AND 
        [Creation Date].[Minute].CurrentMember.Name <= '2016/09/10 15:57'
    )
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Date Sales Schema];
```

---

Try this:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Day Period Sales Count] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      (EXISTING 
        Filter
        (
          [Creation Date].[Minute].MEMBERS
         ,
            [Creation Date].[Minute].CurrentMember.Name >= '2016/09/01 07:27'
          AND 
            [Creation Date].[Minute].CurrentMember.Name <= '2016/09/01 15:57'
        ))
     ,[Measures].[Sales Count]
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Day Period Sales Count] ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    [Creation Date].[Day].[2016/09/01]
   ,[Creation Date].[Day].[2016/09/02]
  } ON ROWS
FROM [Date Sales Schema];
```

Comment: Umm, after first tries of you query I take an error:Syntax error at line 14, column 1, token '('

Comment: And if I want to filtering by minutes, I possible do not need a lines: Filter
    (
      [Creation Date].[Day].MEMBERS
     ,
        [Creation Date].[Day].CurrentMember.Name >= '2016/09/01'
      AND 
        [Creation Date].[Day].CurrentMember.Name <= '2016/09/05'
    )

Comment: @MagentaMill I thought you wanted to filter by date and minute?

Comment: @whyteq 
But if I filter by day and minute , expressions of the form [Creation Date]. [Minute] .CurrentMember.Name> = '2016/09/01 15:57' work correctly in my request. I would like to see this kind of filtering .

Comment: Cool  - should be ok via EXISTS and a range without the sub-select - let me add another script

Comment: Yeah, that's work! And that exactly what I wanted! Thank you!
Please advise the books and articles that will help me learn MDX better?

Comment: @MagentaMill - well initially the thing to do is press the green tick for either me or mxix - then you can also "up" each of our posts to 1 for spending time trying to help. This book is top of my pile of mdx books: https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/mdx-ssas-2012-cookbook/?utm_source=VK-bisherryli&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=1849689601. But mdx takes time and even after time it is still tricky: worth ignoring sql for a while to try to get your head working a little differently.

Comment: Thank you! I press the green tick :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the saw is not quite correct to me the behavior - if a sale was made in 10.02.2016 23:55 , and the filter begins on 10.02.2016 23:54 , the result of a request to show me all the sales for 10.02 :(

Comment: I'm sorry, but maybe you know the reason of this problem and know how to fix it?

Comment: well the SELECT will be based on what is on each axis so it is doing what we want - let me think about it for a bit as there could be a way around this

Comment: Hi! I a little closer to desicion - see attached query in top. But it do not didive results by days..

Comment: I solved my problem by query with two custom members as periods - I build my date-dimension set in the following way: first period from start filter value to end of that day, set of [Day] to last day-1, period from 00:00 of last day to end filter value. It works, but query is so bulky.. Now I will try your decision

Comment: Hmm, your query isn't work at my computer - it requires a ')', after I put the brace , I see an error "No function matches signature 'Existing()'"

Comment: What means 'EXISTING' function in your query?

Comment: you didn't specify the tools you're using - EXISTING is implemented in MS versions of mdx: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145541.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know how your Date/Time dimension/s is/are Built.

Are Minutes/Hours an Attribute of Date? Is there any Hierarchy that relates the two?

You can get your dates as a [RANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146001.aspx). Should even help with performance.

The [Time] part... SSAS isn't prepared to deal with Minutes and Hours as well as Dates unless you actually relate both in an hierarchy, that should make it very straight foward with Range to get all the values. Just use the Range in your sub-select just like whytheq pointed out and use the `[Creation Date].[Day]` on your axis.

```
{[Creation Date].[Full DateTime Hierarchy].&[20160801].&[1557]:[Creation Date].[Full DateTime Hierarchy].&[20160901].&[2359]}
```

But this will very much depend on your Dimension.

Comment: quite a big structure to be missing - I can see this from 2012/13 http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/MONDRIAN-980-